# sum in ng-repeat on multiple array

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I want to show sum of point for each user in this case (cc1,cc2 etc)

Html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="month in months">                          
      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>  
      <td>{{month[0].cc_name}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="points in month[0].cc_point">{{points.point}}</td>                                
</tr>
```

The data is in following format

```
[
    {t_id: "8", fkcc_id: "5", fkagent_id: "1", fktype_id: "1", fkc_id: "1"},
    {t_id: "6", fkcc_id: "1", fkagent_id: "1", fktype_id: "1", fkc_id: "1"},
    {t_id: "7", fkcc_id: "1", fkagent_id: "1", fktype_id: "6", fkc_id: "1"}
]
```

and each record contain

```
{cc_id:"1", cc_name:"cc1", cc_password:"cc1", cc_points:"8"}
```

Comment: What is data and what is record? How are they linked?

Comment: @Vivz record mean i want these fields and are inside data

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="month in months">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{month.cc_name}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="points in month.cc_point">{{points.point}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Code only answers is not encouraged. Please add an explanation as to why the above code will solve OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut unfortunately, you have to code it yourself.

```
<td ng-repeat="points in month.cc_point">{{points.point}}</td>
<td>{{sumPoints(points)}}</td>

$scope.sumPoints = function(points) {
  return points.reduce(function(sum, point) {
    return sum + point.point;
  }, 0);
}

// which is equivalent to
$scope.sumPoints = function(points) {
  var total = 0;

  points.forEach(function(point) {
    total += point.point;
  });

  return total;
}
```